# Can dism /restorehealth be used to restore from a mounted 8.1 ISO?

Tags: windows-8.1, iso-image, dism

On my `x64 Lenovo z580` laptop with `Windows 8.1 x64`, I was trying to install `KB2919355` when I encountered the `error 80073712` which translates to component store corruption.

Since then, I have run the following commands copied here with results:

> 1. sfc /scannow - result: no integrity violation
> 2. dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth - component store is repairable
> 3. dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth - component store is repairable
> 4. dism /online /cleanup-image /analyzecomponentstore component store cleanup recommended: Yes
> 5. dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth dism failed to perform any operation. Either the source is invalid or componentstore is not
>      repairable Error code: 800f081f

Previously, I had upgraded to 8.1 using Windows Update. Now, I have downloaded the 8.1 ISO from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only)

Question: If I mount the 8.1 ISO to drive H:, Can I use the dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:H:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess to repair my componentstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is due to an issue with Windows Update. The DISM /online command uses Windows Update for it's file source. The [article for KB 957310](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957310) should help you to resolve that error message, and then the DISM /online command should work fine once again.

Hope this helps,

Comment: What do you mean by ["outreach"](http://superuser.com/users/98780/winoutreach4) services?

Comment: FYI, /online does not mean it uses Windows Update.  It means you're servicing your current - online image.  The image you booted into (off c:\ or wherever). Alternatively you can use /Image and point it to a VHD (I believe) or another drive provisioned with Windows.  E.g., you boot into a recovery console and use the command with /Image:C:\ instead of /Online (since the online img is the recovery console). Either way it will use WU if needed. Using /LimitAccess prevents it from using Windows Update.